# Solving an inequality $B<n!$ without a calculator or gamma function?

Tags: calculus, elementary-number-theory, inequality

Is there a way to solve $B<n!$ where $B$ is some very large real number (suppose for example $B=10^{17}$) without a calculator or gamma function?

At the very least, to find the nearest integer for $n$ to make the inequality true?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you knew that $B = n!$ (exactly), you could count the trailing zeroes, as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2652536/reverse-factorial).

[EDIT]: $f(n)$, approximation of inverse gamma, is defined as $\frac 1 2 + \frac{L(n)}{W(L(n)/e)}$; where $L(x) = \log \frac{x+c}{\sqrt{2\pi}}$, $c = \frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{e} - \Gamma(k)$.
Here $k$ denotes the positive zero of the digamma function, approximately
$1.461632$. Finally, $W$ is the Lambert function. [Source](https://web.archive.org/web/20171104030158/http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=342551&tstart=0).

For example, starting with $n = 9.3326 \cdot 10^{157}$ and $k \approx 1.4616$ we get $f(n) = 100.9999095692868$ (Mathematica).

Comment: This is interesting but I was looking for a way to do it by hand without any technology.

Comment: I'm afraid it's impossible.

Answer (score 3):

With a log table, you could do it by hand :

Compute $\ln(B)=17 \ln(10)$

Then you just have to sum the log of the numbers :

$$\ln(n!) = \sum_{k=2}^n \ln(k)$$